# Suggested place to put Plugin settings

Tags: vim

I have a plugin place in my `vimrc` that looks like this:

```
 " Plugins {{{
 call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

     " Vim-airline: status-bar for vim: https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline
     Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
     Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'

    "...

call plug#end()
" }}}
```

And then I have a bunch of settings for each of the plugins that look something like:

```
let g:ultisnipseditsplit="tabdo"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger="<tab>"
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger="<s-tab>"
```

What is the suggested place to put the plugin settings? Should it be, for example, inside the Plugin section? (perhaps a 2nd fold-level down?). Should I create a new fold-section for it (one for `Plugins` and one for `Plugin-Settings`?), or where is this suggested place to put all the settings?

Answer (score 2):

It's complete preference. Most people keep them in their vimrc, but if you think it's getting bloated, then sure - extract it to a separate file and you can source it at the bottom of your vimrc like so:

```
source ~/.plugins.vim
```

Answer (score 1):

For plugins, I usually use `~/.vim/after/plugin/config/<name>.vim`. I’m taking advantage of `after` being one of the last directories on the runtime path and anything under `plugin` directories getting sourced at startup.

For as many plugins as I can, I include a check to avoid configuring them (setting mappings, global vars, etc.) if they are not loaded (i.e., don’t exist). For some this is not possible.

[Examples](https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/tree/master/links/vim/after/plugin/config)

Comment: thanks, what is `finally` ? Is that the equivalent of a `return` keyword/statement in other languages?

Comment: Sorry @David542 can you be more specific? I’m not sure I follow what you’re referring to (though vimscript does have a :try/:catch/:finally)

Comment: Ah, perhaps you mean `:finish`? It’s a way to stop a script completely; so if A does `:source B` (which is effectively what’s happening for plugin files), and B does `:finish`, the rest of B is skipped and control is handed back to A. As usual, more in help.